# Derive an expression for the boundary work of the following system

Tags: thermodynamics

Derive an expression for the boundary work of the following system: A friction-less piston is separating a closed cylinder into one compartment with H2O while the other compartment is a vacuum. Now the H2O is heated during process-time ∆t.

I only understand this as the vacuum wanting to pull the piston towards its side and the H2O resisting. I do not know how to create an expression for the boundary work. Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: do you know what role gravity plays in the system, if any?

Comment: Can you please clarify a few points about this question?  Is the cylinder oriented horizontally or vertically?  If it is oriented horizontally, is there something holding the piston in place before it is released at time 0?  Is the H2O a liquid, a vapor, or a combination of liquid and vapor?  By boundary work, do you mean work done on the shell of the closed cylinder (so that the total contents of the cylinder are your system) or work done on the piston (so that the gas alone is your system)?

Answer (score 1):

The catch is:  The piston, although frictionless, has a weight on although not mentioned. That weight is keeping the pressure constant for the water part while heat in coming in. (isobaric)

for energy balance in this example since heat is coming in we have the following:

Q_in  - W_piston = E_in - E_out = Delta H (The enthalpy of the system)

*The total volume is constant and lets name it bigV.
The work in physics is the integral of F * Distance. in thermo it's the integral of pressure times the volume.(V). 
so W = intergal from 1 to 2 of P*dV.  = P* (BigV - BigV/2). 
* He said the the H2O was heated during the proccess so Delta H = (h2 - h1)= C*(T2-T1)   (Note C here is specific heat at constant pressure)